# How to open the mail client in java 1.4

Tags: java, email, client

I would like to open the default mail client in java 1.4, setting the recipient, the subject and the body. 
I've seen that there are the methods Desktop.mail() but they can be used only from 1.6. 
The command javamail that works also with 1.4 seems only to be able to send a mail, without letting the users to control the body and change it.

Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: Why specify an obsolete version of the JRE?

Comment: The application I'm working on is granted on 1.4 java version. There are some tools that don't work with the following java versions. So we have to do programs that are compatible with 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows platform you can use [j.l.Runtime.exec(String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to launch command shell running the [start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command.  The start command accepts a URI in the same format as the Desktop.mail.

From the command shell you can test using:

```
start mailto:foo@bar.org
```

From Java use something like:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "mailto:foo@bar.org"});
p.getErrorStream().close();
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.getInputStream().close();
```